# How do I join two queries in SQL using UNION ALL operation?

Tags: sql

everyone.

This is my first query

```
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL
WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
ORDER BY A.apellidos_Autor DESC ;
```

And this is my second query

```
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL
WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
ORDER BY A.nombres_Autor ASC ;
```

So, I just want to know what do I have to do to join these queries using UNION ALL (and not any JOIN operator). Cz the next is not working for me.

```
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL
WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
ORDER BY A.apellidos_Autor DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL
WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
ORDER BY A.nombres_Autor ASC ;
```

Thank u'all, community.
(I really appreciate any kind of feedback).

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ORDER BY` from the top query.

This will error:

```
SELECT 1 AS i
ORDER BY i
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS i
ORDER BY i
```

This will not:

```
SELECT 1 AS i
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS i
ORDER BY i
```

Comment: you can order once in the query. Union All will make it a one dataset, you cant order it twice. Hence, order at the end of final query only

Answer (score 0):

"order by" is not supported before "union all". Hope it is working for you.

```
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND
AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
UNION ALL
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL
WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
ORDER BY A.nombres_Autor ASC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL
WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
ORDER BY A.apellidos_Autor DESC 
union all
SELECT A.nombres_Autor,A.apellidos_Autor,A.fechaNacimiento_Autor,A.fechaFallecimiento_Autor,L.nombre_Libro,G.nombre_Genero
FROM Autor A , Libro L , Genero G , Autores_X_Libro AXL
WHERE AXL.codigoAutor_AXL = A.codigo_Autor AND AXL.codigoISBN_AXL = L.codigoISBN AND L.codigoGenero_Libro = G.codigo_Genero
ORDER BY A.nombres_Autor ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use two different order by in Union and union all statements. Alternatively it can achieved in the following way.

```
USE tempdb ; 

CREATE TABLE t1 (ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(100)); 
CREATE TABLE t2 (ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(100));  
INSERT INTO t1 (ID, Col1) SELECT 1, 'Col1-t1' UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Col2-t1' UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Col3-t1'; 
INSERT INTO t2 (ID, Col1) SELECT 3, 'Col1-t2' UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Col2-t2' UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'Col3-t2';

SELECT result1.* FROM 
    (SELECT top 1000 tblA.ID, tblA.Col1 FROM t1 AS tblA ORDER BY Col1 desc) AS result1 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT tblB.ID, tblB.Col1 FROM t2 AS tblB ORDER BY Col1 asc

 DROP TABLE t1; 
 DROP TABLE t2;
```

References:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/30/sql-server-union-all-and-order-by-how-to-order-table-separately-while-using-union-all/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).